# Each time you add anything in to a **PriorityQueue**, does it rearrange itself?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

When you use a **PriorityQueue** without a Comparator, does the queue rearrange itself after each offer and if yes, how to avoid it?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid the priority queue rearranging itself? The whole idea of a priority queue is to keep items arranged so that the highest priority item is at the root. If you don't want your data structure to act like a priority queue, then you shouldn't be using a priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc :

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. **The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator** provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.

Yes the queue rearranges itself when elements are added in order to remain ordered. You can't avoid it. If you don't supply a `Comparator`, the natural ordering (defined by the `Compabable` implementation of the element type) is used. If that doesn't suit your purposes, don't use a `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: This isn't strictly correct. Elements are only rearranged if that's necessary to maintain the heap property, but in many cases added values just create new leafs. This is the difference between a priority queue and a sorted structure (array, binary tree, etc.) and why it has better performance than the latter.